# Versafluid Template in Mosaico

Tags: mosaico

Is there a way to have the versafluid template available at Mosaico.io in CiviCRM?

Should I export and upload the .html file in

```
ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/versafluid
```

?

regards

EDIT: I've tried to upload in the directory. The template appears but is not editable as template

Guillaume

Comment: Hi, How do I get hold of versafluid template?

Comment: I've downloaded it directly from Mosaico.io.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to be available anymore

Comment: Reading this old post shows that probably it won't ever be possible : https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico/issues/176